# Selecionar linha de um gridview e passar os valores para um textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar achar uma solução para que quando eu clicar num grid view, ele passe os valores contido na linha para text boxes.

Meu gridview está sendo populado, porém preciso encontrar uma solução para que quando eu clicar na linha, ele execute uma função/método que pegue os valores da linha e execute outra função que já tenho pronta.

Eu procurei várias maneiras, mas não encontro nenhuma maneira descente ou que funcione.

Este é o aspx do meu gridview. De momento eu uso um Button com CommandArguments para executar minha tarefa, mas precisaria alterar isso pra quando clicar sobre a linha do gridview. E a coluna 0 é um template field que expande a linha do grid e mostrando outro grid com outras informações, mas o click na linha será apenas no primeiro grid.

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelBatches" ScrollBars="Auto" Style="width: 60%; height: auto; padding: 10px; border: thin solid #000099; background-color: whitesmoke; position: relative; left: 20%; border-radius: 5px;">
        <div class="rounded_corners" style="width: 100%;">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvWeighingLogBatches" runat="Server" DataKeyNames="ID, Status" GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvHeader"
                CssClass="gvRow" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvWeighingLogBatches_RowDataBound"
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvWeighingLogBatches_PageIdexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvWeighingLogBatches_RomwCommand"
                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="12" HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" Style="width: 100%">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../Imagens/icon_plus.png" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="panelWeighingMaterialLogBatches" runat="server" Style="display: none;">

                                <div class="rounded_corners" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvWeighingMaterialLogBatches" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvChildHeader" CssClass="gvRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gvAltRow"
                                        OnRowDataBound="gvWeighingMaterialLogBatches_RowDataBound" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                        <Columns>

                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../Imagens/icon_plus.png" />
                                                    <asp:Panel ID="panelWeighingLotMaterialLogBatches" runat="server" Style="display: none;">

                                                        <div class="rounded_corners" style="width: 100%;">
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="gvWeighingLotMaterialLogBatches" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                                                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvChildHeader" CssClass="gvRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gvAltRow" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LotManufactID" HeaderText="Lot Fabricante ID" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualAmount" HeaderText="Cantidad Real" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpireDate" HeaderText="Fecha de Expiración" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="WeighingDateTime" HeaderText="Hora de la Fecha de Pesaje" />
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </asp:Panel>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id de Registro del Material de Pesaje" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nombre del Ingrediente" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MinAmount" HeaderText="Mínimo" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetAmount" HeaderText="Necesario" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="MaxAmount" HeaderText="Máximo" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualAmount" HeaderText="Real" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="WeighingDateTime" HeaderText="Hora de la Fecha de Pesaje" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Estado" />

                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>

                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="linkBtnViewBatches" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("BatchID") %>' CommandName="View" Text="Ver Lote"></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID de Registro de Pesaje" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchID" HeaderText="ID de Lote" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nombre del Producto" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualBatchSize" HeaderText="Tamaño Real del Lote" DataFormatString="{0:F3}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchPriority" HeaderText="Prioridad de Lote" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestedStartTime" HeaderText="Hora de inicio Solicitada" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Estado" />

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Compartilhe o código do que você já conseguiu fazer.

Comment: é AspNetForms?. se puder disponibilize o código!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais simples e objetiva de fazer tal código sem muitas informações na pergunta é:

Coloque um `CommandField` (`<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"  />`) no `GridView`, ***exemplo completo***:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" 
    Width="691px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nome" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"  /> // comando de seleção ...
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

apos ter criado isso adicione o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` pela caixa de propriedades e eventos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e nesse evento que acontece a rotina quando for selecionado alguma linha, e o código abaixo representa um ideia de como fazer:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = ((GridView)sender);
    int index = grid.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(grid.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, out var id))
        {
            //id tem o valor correspondente da primeira coluna
            //onde o valor é o que identifica a linha
        }
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de tela:**

- ***Tela sem seleção***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- ***Tela com seleção***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom esse seria o processo, mas, no meu caso exemplo eu utilizei o `Entity Framework` para persistir e recuperar informações e o código completo do `WebForm`:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Load_Grid();
        }
    }

    protected void Load_Grid()
    {
        using (BaseDadosEntities baseDados = new BaseDadosEntities())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = baseDados.Credit.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = ((GridView)sender);
        int index = grid.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(grid.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, out var id))
            {
                using (BaseDadosEntities baseDados = new BaseDadosEntities())
                {
                    Credit cr = baseDados.Credit.Find(id);
                    if (cr != null)
                    {
                        TxtId.Text = cr.Id.ToString();
                        TxtName.Text = cr.Name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

agora pode adaptar ao seu modo com a sua rotina, só olhar o código e reproduzir. Isso é um exemplo e particularmente um primeiro esboço para passar realmente a ideia inicial.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Propriedade GridView.SelectedRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ASP .NET - Como obter valores da linha selecionada em um GridView](http://www.macoratti.net/10/11/asp_vlsc.htm)
- [GridView - Selecionar a linha clicando em qualquer coluna](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/gridview-selecionar-a-linha-clicando-em-qualquer-coluna/4947)
- [Selecionar a linha do GridView ao clicar no Asp.Net](http://dprogrammer.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/selecionar-linha-do-gridview-ao-clicar.html#.Wg-jdEqnHcs)
- [Selecionando Linhas de forma dinâmica dentro do GridView](https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/csharp/313_selecionando-linhas-de-forma-din-mica-dentro-do-gridview)

Comment: Virgilio, sua explicação foi muito construtiva pra mim, mas tentei adaptar ao meu código e deu erro de sintaxe nessa parte:

Comment: `protected void gvAdjstBatchesCancel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = ((GridView)sender);
            int index = grid.SelectedRow.RowIndex;

            if (index > 0)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(grid.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text, out var id))
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }`
Nessa parte eu coloquei [1] pois a coluna 0 é um template field que abre outro grid dentro dele mesmo de forma dinâmica.

Comment: @MatheusAlvesdeOliveira na sua pergunta coloque o seu `aspx` da sua `GridView` para que eu possa te informar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: eu disponibilizei o aspx do meu grid para que você possa me ajudar se for possível.

Comment: @MatheusAlvesdeOliveira não faltou colocar o evento? ou seja, `SelectedIndexChanged` no `GridView` observe que no GridView tem a referencia do método se não ele não funciona!

Comment: esse é o código sem as alterações, eu fiz como você me mostrou e deu erro na parte que te mostrei aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Não está igual não @MatheusAlvesdeOliveira dá uma olhada certinho o evento no seu gridview não está registrado... e o erro eu não to vendo se mostrou código não erro?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69122/discussion-between-matheus-alves-de-oliveira-and-virgilio-novic).

Comment: O erro aparece na linha 
`if (int.TryParse(grid.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text, out var ID))`

Invalid expression term ')'

Comment: @MatheusAlvesdeOliveira ai o erro é outro amigo é parenteses entendeu, é algo local tem como colocar o seu código no contexto da pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Saudações.

Vamos supor um grid : meuDataGridView

3 colunas:

**Nome**   |   **Idade**    |   **Sexo**

Carlos  | - 12 - | - M

Maria   | - 18 - | - F

João    | - 16 - | - M

```
// passando valor da linha selecionada para textBox
textBoxNome.Text = Convert.ToString(meuDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
textBoxIdade.Text = Convert.ToString(meuDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
textBoxSexo.Text = Convert.ToString(meuDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
```

**No código acima:**

`CurrentRow.Cells` = Linha atual selecionada

`Cells[x]` = numero da celula/coluna referente a linha selecionada

Dica: para selecionar toda a linha e não apenas uma célula do dataGridView, selecione o grid e nas propriedades em **SelectionMode** mude para **FullRowSelect**